# putObject via presigned url on encrypted S3 bucket returns signature does not match

Tags: vba, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have serverless aws lambda that will get/put object onto encrypted S3 buckets via presigned urls. getObject works perfectly. putObject generates `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error once I encrypt the bucket and I cannot understand why. I have played with headers and such, but still cannot get it to work. Code / policies below:

**lambda**

```
    const generatepresignedurl = (req, res, callback) => {

    var fileurls = [];
    const body = JSON.parse(req.body);
    const theBucket = body['theBucket'];
    const theKey = body['theKey'];
    const theContentType = body['theContentType'];
    const theOperation = body['theOperation'];

    /*setting the presigned url expiry time in seconds, also check if user making the request is an authorized user
     for your app (this will be specific to your app’s auth mechanism so i am skipping it)*/
    const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 60;

    if (theOperation == 'getObject') {
        var params = {
            Bucket: theBucket,
            Key: theKey,
            Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
        };
    } else {
        var params = {
            Bucket: theBucket,
            Key: theKey,
            Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds,
            ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control',
            ContentType: theContentType,
            ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'
        };
    }

    s3.getSignedUrl(theOperation, params, function (err, url) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error Getting Presigned URL from AWS S3');
            // callback(null, ({ success: false, message: 'Pre-Signed URL error', urls: fileurls }));
            callback(null, {error: err});
        }
        else {
            fileurls[0] = url;
            console.log('Presigned URL: ', fileurls[0]);
            callback(null, { success: true, message: 'AWS SDK S3 Pre-signed urls generated successfully.', urls: fileurls });
        }
    });

}
```

Calling code is here:

**Generate PreSigned Url**

```
Function callStandAloneAWSService(lambda As String, request As String, contentType As String) As String

    Dim httpserver As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

    With httpserver

        Dim theURL As String
        theURL = AWS_WEBSERVICE_URL_DEV

        .Open "POST", theURL & lambda 'variable that contains generatepresignedurl

        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", contentType

        .send request

        Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4 'make sure we are ready to recieve response

        callStandAloneAWSService = .responseText

    End With

End Function
```

**Upload to PreSigned URL** (original question did not have serversidencryption header)

```
Function uploadToPreSignedURL(url As String, whichFile As String, contentType) As Boolean

    'code to create binaryFile

    Dim httpserver As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

    With httpserver

        .Open "POST", url
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "text/plain" 'contentType
        .send binaryFile
        Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4 'make sure we are ready to recieve response

        If Len(.responseText) = 0 Then

            uploadToPreSignedURL = True

        Else

            'extract error message from xml and write to report mail

        End If

    End With

End Function
```

**bucket policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybiggetybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybiggetybucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

FWIW, I can run this via aws cli and get it to work:

> aws s3api put-object --bucket mybiggetybucket --key test.json --body package-lock.json --server-side-encryption "AES256"

Comment: Does your upload work if you temporarily suppress the S3 bucket policy?

Comment: @jarmod yes, it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote the [Server Side Encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html) docs:

> You can't enforce SSE-S3 encryption on objects that are uploaded using
> presigned URLs. You can specify server-side encryption only with the
> AWS Management Console or an HTTP request header. For more
> information, see [Specifying Conditions in a Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html).

I was able to get something similar working. I needed to use PUT rather than POST, and I needed to supply `x-amz-server-side-encryption:AES256` as a header, as follows:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const params = {
  Bucket: 'mybucket',
  Key: 'myfolder/myfile.txt',
  Expires: 60 * 60,
  ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control',
  ContentType: 'text/plain',
  ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256',
};

const axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256',
  },
};

const uploadTextFile = (presignedurl) => {
  axios.put(presignedurl, 'some text here', axiosConfig).then((res) => {
    console.log('File uploaded');
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
};

s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, (err, url) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Pre-signed URL:', url);
    uploadTextFile(url);
  }
});
```

Comment: Of course! i didn't even think to try pass the encryption headers in my call to get the signedurl even though I thought to try it :) ... Worked beautifully! Thank God! This was plaguing me all week.

Comment: You’re issuing a PUT and supplying the SSE header and it’s failing with the original signature problem? Or something else?

Comment: Yes. Same error `SignatureDoesNotMatch` whether I issue a PUT or POST. I also moved the encryption into the `callPresignedURL` function to mimick exactly what your answered suggested.

Comment: Make sure the credentials are correct. Make sure that your signature request and the subsequent call using it have the same HTTP headers. Make sure that the clock is synced.

Comment: thanks jarmod - i just figured it out. I had to take out the `Content-Type` header in the call to generate the presigned url and only pass in the call to the actual url since i was already setting in the params of the lambda :)

Comment: For all those who come after the final solution was to add the encryption header `.setRequestHeader "x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256"` into the `uploadToPreSignedURL` and remove the `Content-Type` header from `callStandAloneAWSService` since it was already being passed in the params of the `generatepresignedurl` lambda.